# disable rcpt to command

Tags: smtp, telnet, zimbra

I would like to ask how to disable rcpt to command from my postfix configuration in my local zimbra mail server in order to protect it from sending mails using telnet without any authentication.

and any further advises to protect and harden the security of my mail server.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable RCPT TO without breaking SMTP.

The proper way to prevent unauthorized mail is to require authentication in postfix.

http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html